# autocomplete not working with ajax generated textbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

In my page I am using ajax to generate/show a textbox after button click. I am using autocomplete functionality in this textbox, but autocomplete call is not firing off. I cannot see the autocomplete call in firebug when I try to enter anything in the textbox.

But at the same time it is working fine in a plain test page which has a textbox (without ajax generation), so that means jQuery, autocomplete files are okay.

I am suspecting ajax generated textbox's ID should be called in autocomplete function in a different way. I have attached below what way I tried.

```
<script>
    $(function(){  
        $("#orderingparty2").autocomplete("auto/findparty.cfm");
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the code adding autocomplete to the ajax function which is generating the input box. Else you can trigger the autcomplete event on any event like onclick.

```
$("#orderingparty2").live('click',function(event) 
{

$(this).autocomplete("auto/findparty.cfm");


});
```

Comment: Hi Abdul, I got the livequery file, is it neeeded to just include in my page will make efffect?

Comment: include it into your html . and replace live with livequery   $("#orderingparty2").livequery('click',function(event)  
{ 
 
$(this).autocomplete("auto/findparty.cfm"); 
 
 
});

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the autocomplete call in the ajax handler that appends the textbox, something like this:

```
$.ajax({  
   ... 
   success(function(...) {
      $('<input type="text">')             
         .attr(...)
         .css(...)
         .appendTo('#myForm')
         .autocomplete("auto/findparty.cfm");  
   })
   ...
});
```

Comment: I have initialized the autocomplete plugin like this.... $("#PaymentIn").load('/Bank/_PaymentIn/', function () {
                    $(this).find('#ChequeNo').autocomplete();
                    });

     $("input#ChequeNo").autocomplete({...but its not working