# Using jquery & ajax autocomplete when generating the input after the page is ready

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I searched the forum about this, I found this: [autocomplete not working with ajax generated textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068382/autocomplete-not-working-with-ajax-generated-textbox) and this: [jQuery autocomplete failing after dynamically adding additional text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719382/jquery-autocomplete-failing-after-dynamically-adding-additional-text-input-field)

but each time, it's document ready functions whereas mine is on keyup. I think it makes the difference.

Here is the situation: I have those functions to deal with autocomplete input. It uses jQuery and Ajax:

```
var truid = "";

$(function(){
    $(".autocomp").keyup(function() {
        var realid = $(this).attr('id');
        var searchid = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'search=' + searchid;

        if(searchid != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_complete.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#result_"+realid).html(html).show();
                    truid=realid;
                }
            });
        }
        return false;    
    });

    $(".autoresult").on("click",function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var $id = $clicked.find('.auto_id').text();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#' + truid).val(decoded);
        $('#' + truid + "_true").val($id);
    });

    $(document).on("click", function(e) { 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("autocomp")) {
            $("#result_" + truid).fadeOut(); 
        }
    });

    $('.autocomp').click(function() {
        truid = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#result_" + truid).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

I use generally this input to use with this autocomplete function:

```
<input type="text" class="autocomp" id="uniqueid" />
<input type="hidden" id="uniqueid_true" name="uniqueid" />
<div class="autoresult" id="result_uniqueid"></div>
```

When I put this piece of code directly in the html when document is ready, it works fine.

But when I generate those inputs in ajax, then, the autocomplete doesn't work, nothing happens when I make suggestions.

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Do the same with your `keyup`-function what you did with your `click`-functions:

Instead of...:

```
$(".autocomp").keyup(function() { [...] });
```

Write...:

```
$(".autocomp").on("keyup", function() { [...] });
```

Comment: Unfortunetaly, it's not making the job... It's still the same:working with the DOM ready input, not with the ajax created...